# Is there a way to get a value stored in ram on the server from a page in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, nuxt.js

I'm coming from the Nuxt environment so I'll use Nuxt to explain my issue.
In the footer of my webpage, I put links to other websites I've built. In Nuxt, I get the list of other web pages I've built from the database when my app server starts up and store it in `privateRuntimeConfig`. On the page, I check if the code is running on the server with `process.client`. If so, I simply get the list from `privateRuntimeConfig` and put the list in the footer.

How would I do this in Blazor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a service and register it as Singleton in your program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SiteLinkService>();
```

This service holds a list with your links:

```
public class SiteLinkService
{
    private IList<string> links;
    public IList<string> GetLinks()
    {
        if (links == null)
        {
            links = //load from database;
        }

        return links;
    }
}
```

Then in your page inject the service and call:

```
@inject SiteLinkService siteLinkService;

<footer>@siteLinkService.GetLinks()</footer>
```

PS: You can also make it as a static class, but is preferable as a service.